# How to get the current manager's name for each employee and add it as a new column in the same table?

Tags: left-join, self-join

I have a table `Employees` with `emp_no` and employees' info but there isn't a column specifying their manager at all.

The names of the managers and their `emp_no` are in the `Employees` table with the rest of the staff. The managers' `emp_no` and `dept_no` are present in the `dept_manager` table.
The active managers have value `9999-01-01` in column `to_date` in `dept_manager`.
In a 3rd table `dept_emp`, I have the `emp_no` and `dept_no` of each employee.

I tried to use `left join` to add the manager names against the employees'names but I get an error:

```sql
SELECT (concat(first_name, ' ',last_name)) as EmployeeName, 
(concat(first_name, ' ', last_name)) as Managersname,
FROM employees AS emp 
LEFT JOIN dept_manager AS dm ON emp.emp_no=dm.emp_no
LEFT JOIN dept_emp as de on dm.dept_no=de.dept_no and dm.to_date='9999-01-01';
```

Any better ideas about how to get the results right?

Thanks,
GV

Comment: It is missing information on how to know which Manager corresponds to an Employee. Before trying to solve it with SQL, try to find a way to get that info "in english"

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Stop trying to code your overall goal & explain what you expected instead from the given code & why.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (concat(emp.first_name, ' ', emp.last_name)) as EmployeeName, 
(concat(dm.first_name, ' ', dm.last_name)) as Managersname 
FROM employees AS emp LEFT JOIN dept_manager AS dm ON emp.emp_no=dm.emp_no  
WHERE dm.to_date='9999-01-01';
```